Is there a better way of listening socket in infinite loop in PHP?
I have the following code for listening socket for client connections
<?php
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$port = "1234";
socket_bind($socket, '192.168.1.1', $port);
socket_listen($socket);
socket_set_nonblock($socket);

while (true) {
    if (($newConnection = socket_accept($socket)) !== false) {
        $childProcessID = pcntl_fork();
        if ($childProcessID == -1) {
            throw new Exception('Could not fork');
        } else if (!$childProcessID) {
            $myProcessID = getmypid();
            $lastActive = time();

            while (true) {
                if (socket_recv($newConnection, $currentMsg, 2045, MSG_DONTWAIT) >= 1) {
                    // Process Message

                }
            }
        }
?>

There's no syntax issue or functionality wise in the code except when I run it, due to the while loop, it's taking most of the CPU cycles. Is there a better way of listening the socket connection?

why do you use socket_set_nonblock?

Where is the code to leave the while loop on hangup?

Not directly related to your problem, but I just want to make sure you are running this on the CLI and not through a web server

You're missing some close braces.

There's no need to use non-blocking sockets and MSG_DONTWAIT if you fork a new process to handle each connection. That's generally only done if a single process is multiplexing all the sockets. And then you would normally use select() to wait for something to happen on one of the sockets.
